# ASP.NET Core MVC : I can't prevent back button

Tags: button, asp.net-core-mvc, back, asp.net-core-2.2

I am working with ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC.

I try this code in JavaScript:

```
 window.history.forward(1);
```

but it did not work. I want to stop back button after logout.

Please help me

Comment: there is no global.asax.cs file in core2.2

Comment: i try also [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]

Comment: it gives error when try to login by Keycloak

Comment: Is there any progress sir? If you feel my post is helpful to you, could you pls accept it as the answer by pick the √ beside it? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ?

I newly created an asp.net core 2.1 mvc project and I add these code in home page, then after starting the program, browser comes to home page, then I click to visit "about" page, and then click the back button in the browser, then it can't go back to the home page. The code snippet is at the bottom of the index.cshtml file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout("window.history.forward();", 0);
</script>
```

Per my test, even using code below also worked

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
</script>
```

As the executing order is from top to bottom,  first and  next. All code or doms executed, then trigger the onload() method, and certainly, though `$(document).ready` is before `window.onload()` but they all behind the other scripts.